# Accessing data of referencing project in referenced project in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a login project which authenticates the user(....obviously) and another project Load which is referenced in the login project. Now, I need to access a data member of a class of the login project in a class of the Load project but how do I do this without running into circular dependency? I don't see how referencing login dll or creating a separate project referencing login and in turn  referenced by Load would solve this.

Both projects are windows forms.

Thanks for your patience. I know it's a silly question and I am truly sorry about that.

Comment: Try putting that in a session and access in load project.

Comment: There seems to be a lack of details in this question that make it somewhat difficult to answer.  There is no mention of classes, only projects which means that the issue is only partially defined.  If a class A in one project X references (uses) class B in project Y and further class B references class C in project Y then the answer is what MichealOchajo indicated in his answer: define an interface for class C in project Y, have class C implement the interface (this works because project X references project Y).   In this way class B can use just the interface along with an IoC.

Comment: @SteveEllinger I have added a bit more details. Basically Project A is referencing Project B and I want to access a data member of class X of Project A in a class Y of Project B. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is like this:

```
Project A
+-> References Project B
+-  Class X

Project B
+-  Class Y
    +- Needs Data from Class X
```

There are two ways to resolve this:

### Option A

Move the data from Class X that you need in Class Y to some class in Project B. Now both Projects have access to the information.

### Option B

Move the date from Class X that you need in Class Y to some class in a third Project C and reference that from both other Projects. *Large solutions often have a 'Data' or 'Model' Project that holds data classes used by multiple other projects*

Comment: Yeah that's it. Thanks. BTW kickass representation

Answer (score 0):

One way of dealing with circular references is: Extract interfaces from both "login" and "load" project and put them in to a single project, which you will reference.

Comment: I am actually working with windows forms. I'm sorry I forgot to mention that and thanks for teaching me a new approach